# Can I input a number into Excel and have Excel display it as a time in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

This may not be possible but I would like to be able to enter a number and have it display that number as a time in the same cell.  To make it look a little neater and so only what is needed is shown.

Ex.  Type 1445 into cell A1,  A1 displays 2:45pm

I read a little about VBA and macros but am not familiar with them.

1. If so, would I be able to use the same macro to do this for 14
   inputs (7 in and out times) per person?
2. If I were to copy a person's timesheet for a new person, would it work the same for the copied version without having to do anything?
3. Would I be able to perform a calculation based off of the input not
   the displayed.  Reasons are explained below:

I am redoing a timesheet converter for work.  The old one cannot convert 24:00 or 48:00 to decimal format correctly when it is from days added together.

I have it where it will correctly find the hrs and mins between the two times and subtract a lunch time while still in number format.  I can then display the lunch as 30mins and total daily hrs as 8hrs 20mins.  It will also calculate daily pay automatically.

I was wondering if this is possible before I try and spend more time on it.  I have never used Excel before working here.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**There are Several methods to convert Numbers/Decimal Number into Excel Time Format:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter Numbers/Decimal Numbers and keep the Cell Format **General**.
- Formula in Cell `I87`: `=H87/1440`
- Apply Custom Format `[h]:mm` to Cells.
- Formula in Cell `I92`:     `=H92/86400`
- Apply Custom Format `[h]:mm:ss` to Cells.
- Formula in Cell `I97`:  `=H97/24`
- Apply Custom Format `h:mm` to Cells.
- Fill Formula down.

[image]

- Press **ALT+F11** to open VB editor, then **Copy & Paste** this code as Standard Module.

  ```
  Sub NumbersToTime()

  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim iHours As Integer
  Dim iMins As Integer

  For Each rCell In Selection
      If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) And Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then
          iHours = rCell.Value \ 100
          iMins = rCell.Value Mod 100
          rCell.Value = (iHours + iMins / 60) / 24
          rCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
      End If
  Next
  End Sub
  ```
- Select Cells & **RUN** the Macro.

*You get this:*

[image]

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

This is for cell **A1** specifically.  Place the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim s As String, d As Date

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Clear
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    s = Target.Text
    l = Len(s)
    If l < 4 Then
        s = String(4 - l, "0") & s
    End If

    d = TimeSerial(Left(s, 2), Right(s, 2), 0)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Clear
        Target.Value = d
        Target.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is based only on the formula. The Logic is as under :
1.  First Decide the "a.m." or p"p.m." Suffix by Testing Number Less than 1159 or not 
2.  Convert the number in to Text Format
3.  Decide the Left Two Digits for Hours, depending on Lenth of Text = 3 or 4
4.  Decide the Right Two Digits for Minutes

Start :
 1. In First Row Give Titles As Below
Column 1. "Number", Column 2 "Time", Column 3. Leave Blank for Clarity
Column 4. "Text", Column 5. "Left2", Column 6. " Right2", Column 7. "Hour Digit", Column. 8 "ampm"

Enter the Formulae as Under :

In Cell B2 Enter the Formula : =IF(A2=0, " 12 Mid Night", IF( A2=1200, " 12 Noon",H2&"="&G2&I2))

In Cell D2 Enter the Formula : =TEXT(A2,"####")

In Cell E2 Enter the Formula :  =IF(LEN(E2)=3,LEFT(E2,1),LEFT(E2,2))

In Cell F2 Enter the Formula : =RIGHT(E2,2)

In Cell G2 Enter the Formula : =IF(M2=" a.m.",F2,F2-12)

In Cell H2 Enter the Formula :  =IF(A2<1159," a.m."," p.m.")

Start Entering Time in Number Format down the row in Colun A
Time is Displayed in Column B in the Desired Format :

Number  Time        Text    L2  R2  Hour Digit  ampm
1445    2=45 p.m.   1445    14  45  2    p.m.
810 8=10 a.m.       810 8   10  8    a.m.
0    12 Mid Night                        a.m.
2155    9=55 p.m.       2155    21  55  9    p.m.
123 1=23 a.m.       123 1   23  1    a.m.
800 8=00 a.m.       800 8   00  8    a.m.
1200     12 Noon        1200    12  00  0    p.m.
345 3=45 a.m.       345 3   45  3    a.m.

I tried to paste the Copied Answer Table of Excel but it gives a very small image type icon. The above pasted portion works better but somehow the direct conversion in the  Reply Section, it gets jumbled.

Thanks.

My Request : I am new to Stack Exchange so I dont know how to answer, how to use the exact copied portion of my excel file. Even if I write properly taking care of formats, again in the Reply Part It gets all mixed, spoiling clarity of the solution.
Anyway, I will learn with the time, it seems.
Thanks, Again.